# autoUpdate not working for p:growl and p:messages in primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to test the p:growl and p:messages using the attribute autoUpdate, but it doesn't work, it's a very simple code though.

My page (primes.xhtml):

```
<h:head/>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:messages autoUpdate="true"/>
        <p:commandButton action="#{dateBean.testErr}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

the DateBean class:

```
@ManagedBean
public class DateBean {

    public String testErr(){

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("test error"));
        return null;
    }
}
```

whenever I hit the commandButton the server gives me the following warning:

"WARNING: There are some unhandled FacesMessages, this means not every FacesMessage had a chance to be rendered.
These unhandled FacesMessages are: - test error"

But messages aren't displayed in the page, neither do the growl.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem with Mojarra 2.1.26 and PrimeFaces 3.5. Which JSF impl/version and PF version exactly? What does the ajax response body contain?

Comment: I'm using Myfaces 2.0, the action should do nothing but add a new message to be displayed by p:messages or p:growl whenever it the message is added.

Comment: Which MyFaces version exactly? The "2.0" is just a spec version. Is it 2.0.0? This is ancient! (almost 4 years old) It's currently already at 2.1.12. Have you tried it just to exclude it from being the cause? Also you still haven't told about the PF version and ajax response body.

Comment: sorry, forgot to specify that it is 2.0.2 and primefaces 3.5
I will try a newer implementation and see what would happen.
I'm not sure about the ajax response (don't know much about ajax except that the above code goes to the server and runs the action, since there is nothing specified to be updated nothing is updated), I thought that the autoUpdate attribute will detect that an ajax request was sent, thus the messages tag should be updated)

Comment: Ajax response body is visible in network monitor of browser's webdeveloper toolset (press F12 in Chrome/Firefox/Firebug/IE>=9)

Comment: @a.u.r Have you tried setting `globalOnly="true"`, since you didn't supply any clientId with the message.

Comment: Well, it seems that BalusC was right, I tried it with a newer implementation of JSF and it worked normally.

Answer (score 8):

**The newest:** Primefaces 7 doesn't support this p:growl and p:messages **autoUpdate="true"** attribute. Simply it doesn't work, you get the server warning above: "WARNING: There are some unhandled FacesMessages,..."

Use this instead of autoUpdate="true" attribute:

```
<p:messages>
    <p:autoUpdate />
</p:messages>
```

and this

```
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true">
    <p:autoUpdate />
</p:growl>
```

#### See also:

- [PrimeFaces 6.2 - 7.0 Migration guide](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide#62-to-70)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that link to the migration guide.
It was mentioned often but is not linked in the 7.0 Release on Github and there is no section for migration guides in the documentation section of the project website.